# iron-router data function for single item page

Tags: meteor, iron-router

```
 Router.route('/product/:product_id', {
  template: 'productmain',
  //data: function() {
  //  //console.log(this.params.product_id);
  //  return this.params.product_id;
  //}
  data: function (){
    _id  = this.params.product_id;

    product = Products.find({pid: _id});

    templateData = {
      _id: _id,
      product: Products.find({pid: _id}),
      title: product.title
    };

    return templateData;
  }
})
```

title & product seem to be empty, any ideas?

I can't fathom why these two are not working in my template:

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-xs-9">
  <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
</div>

<div class="col-md-9 col-xs-9">
  <h1>{{ product.title }}</h1>
</div>
```

If I do a Products.find({pid: _id}) in a helper function it works fine but I need a different display for this one product, hope that make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `product = Products.findOne({pid: _id});` in your `data` function. You're showing an individual product in a template, not a cursor.

You could simplify the whole thing as follows:

```
Router.route('/product/:product_id', {
  template: 'productmain',
  data: function (){
    return Products.findOne({pid: this.params.product_id});
  }
});
```

then in your html just do:

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-xs-9">
  <h1>{{_id}}{{ title }}</h1>
</div>
```

Basically the `data` function returns a single object which becomes `this` for the template. All attributes of `this` are available without prefixing, i.e. `{{this._id}}` can be shortened to `{{_id}}`

Comment: Your Logic is sound, However this is still not working. are there any debugging tools you are aware of? If you need more information please do let me know.

Comment: I was searching for a string :\ sorry,
var product_id = parseInt(this.params._id);
return Products.findOne({pid: product_id});
works fine!

Comment: Become familiar with the chrome inspector, the nodejs inspector (`meteor debug`) and the mongodb console (`meteor mongo`)